# VS2010, flex & bison, redefinition and syntax errors with no line numbers

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, bison, flex-lexer

I've set up flex and bison, figured out how to get them to work properly, and also weeded out the bulk of errors which made it into the generated code, now I am convinced that the 3 remaining errors are not my fault:

```
Error   10  error C2371: 'free' : redefinition; different basic types

Error   8   error C2059: syntax error : '=' path...\parser.tab.c

Error   9   error C2040: 'malloc' : 'void *(size_t)' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *(size_t)' path...\parser.tab.c
```

The file parser.tab.c is about 1600 lines long, so I don't intend to look for a suspicious '=' through the whole file. Also it redirects to the code in my own files with the `#line` instruction (didn't even know it existed before) so it would complain about my own files, as it did before.

As I said, there are no line numbers, the field is empty, which is why I sought refuge here, I have no clue where to even look. Double clicking the error doesn't do anything either. It is not an issue with my installation, I opened two other projects in C# and XNA and they behave fine.

Flex and bison have been giving me a real hard time so far, so I can't wait to get them to compile correctly.

**Edit: Bison file**

```
%{

#include "lex.yy.c"
#include "stdlib.h"

#define E_IDENTIFIER 300
#define E_FUNCTION 301

int currentBrackets = 0;
%}

%token E_FUNCTION E_IDENTIFIER

%%

expression: E_IDENTIFIER {return E_IDENTIFIER;}

%%
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few problems.

```
%{

/* This is wrong. Do not include the lexer in the parser.
 * Compile it separately and link the two files together. */
#include "lex.yy.c"

/* Should be <stdlib.h>, and needs to come before any other code */
#include "stdlib.h"

/* Bison will define these symbols; you shouldn't do so. And
 * you particularly shouldn't do so as macros because Bison
 * defines them as enums. */
#define E_IDENTIFIER 300
#define E_FUNCTION 301

int currentBrackets = 0;
%}
```

So your bison prolog should look like this:

```
%{
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int currentBrackets = 0;
%}
```

And your flex prolog needs to include the *header* file generated by bison.

```
%{
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   // See note
   #include "parser.tab.h"
%}
```

The `free` and `malloc` errors come from including the generated scanner *before* including `stdlib.h` (and from leaving out the `#include <stdlib.h>` from the flex prolog). The syntax error with `=` comes from the fact that bison will automatically generate an `enum` with the values of the tokens, and your macro definition causes the enum to be syntactically incorrect.

Note: it's important to tell bison to generate a header file; you do that using the `-d` command-line option. That header file needs to be `#include`d in any file which uses the token names. (Normally, that's just the scanner, but occasionally there will be other translation units which need it as well.)

The name of the header file depends on the name of the source file and the way you invoke bison; I don't know how things will work on Windows, but I usually use the `-o` option to provide an explicit name for the generated `.c` file and if you do that, the header file will have the same name with the `.c` substituted with `.h`.

Comment: Ok, the #include parts did the trick mostly, did the -d and so on, now I still get a syntax error which blames "constant" not to match, this is in the bison generated file, no indication of line, I did a search across all documents and it only appears once in a comment, if I change that I get the same error so that's not it.. At least we got it down to one error

Comment: `error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'`, in parser.tab.c, the line field is empty. C2059 is generic for a syntax error I believe.

Comment: @user3079666: To the best of my limited understanding of the vagaries of MSVC, that error message means that it has unexpectedly encountered a constant (eg a number) when it expected something else. Could well be the result of a non-standard macro predefined by MSVC or in some include file.

Comment: Well this is discouraging... so I start a brute force search through the file?

Comment: Actually my concern is more about the fact that it does not point to any line, as it should do and has done consistently in the past, I suppose this is more of a VS question than a flex-bison question

Comment: @user3079666: I completely agree. I do not know why the error messages don't have line numbers and it is certainly a pain, but I don't think it has anything to do with bison.

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying, you did reduce the number of errors to one so it was worth it for me, if I get any useful results I'll update

Comment: @user3079666: You did remove all the `#define`s, right? I know zip-all about VS, so I can just offer generic suggestions: (1) Try a different VS version. (2) add the `%no-lines` bison option to suppress `#line` directives, in case those are causing the VS problem. (3) Failing that, get VS to just preprocess the parser source, and then compile the preprocessed output. (In case macro expansions cause problems with the display of line numbers.) (4) Binary search the error. Compile half the generated file, then three-quarters, etc., until the error appears. A dozen iterations should suffice.

Comment: Hm, it wasn't the `#line` directive, and a note for those on windows, it is `--no-lines` for some reason.. I'll try it on VS2013 when it comes around to understanding that I do have the room required, until then I'm trying to figure a way to do the binary search, I believe I did manage the preprocessing but it didn't fix it, I'll also see if I there's another way it can be done

Comment: VS decided to point me to the error, turns out I had used the same name as a token in bison and as a #define in flex, so bison was trying to give it another value, should have suspected that tokens are considered new values, would have saved a couple of days :/